# Follow random link in the current page every 10 seconds

Tags: random-walk

I cannot find a random walker, that starts with a given URL and goes to a random link in the page every X seconds. Just for fun.

- it can be a Firefox extension
- it can be a html source file
- or it can be a webpage with this functionality somewhere on the web.

I suppose this should be a few lines in your favorite script?

Comment: And what do you want achive with this thing?

Comment: I said - just for fun. You can also say I want to visualise the random walk (used i.e. by Pagerank) or I'm just curious to "autoplay" the Internet starting from any point.